# ¿Como puedo llenar un arreglo con numeros aleatorios? java

Tags: java

Soy muy nuevo en esto y no comprendo cual es mi error, agradecería que alguien me pudiera ayudar.

Lo que quiero hacer es crear un arreglo de tamaño 10 y que lo rellene con números aleatorios del 1 al 100

Por lo que entiendo si se genera un arreglo de tamaño 10, pero no me entrega números
[image]

```
static void vectores(){
    int[] A= new int[10];
    for (int pos = 0; pos < 10; pos++){
        A[pos] = (int)(Math.random()*99+1);
        
        System.out.println(A[pos]);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    vectores();
```

Comment: Bienvenido KinzDal, te recomiendo que sustituyas las imágenes por texto por favor, de esta manera para la persona que vaya a ayudarte le será de mejor ayuda el poder copiar el texto y llevarlo a su equipo, con la imagen no se puede. Además, si el día de mañana la imagen no está, tu pregunta no le servirá a nadie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás mostrando siempre la misma posición, cambia `System.out.println(A);` por `System.out.println(A[pos]);`

De esta manera, en cada recorrido del bucle, se mostrará precisamente el valor del arreglo en ese instante dado.